# I used ssh-keyscan in production environment. is it possible to revert back?

Tags: linux, ssh, ssh-keys, ssh-keygen

I used ssh-keyscan in production environment, after got to know it may allows MITM. I check in known_hosts files, fingerprint is not there. where can i check or is there any option?

Answer (score 2):

The known_hosts file does not contain finger prints, only the full (public) keys that you added.

To display the finger prints use `ssh-keygen -l -f ~/.ssh/known_hosts` and if you like to add the `-v` switch to also show a visual ASCII art representation of the key is supplied with the fingerprint.

```
ssh-keygen -l -f ~/.ssh/known_hosts

2048 SHA256:2ggdJPUVnjTHdG36iGw7Du8knzvPSLgF6fTBUhzn3d5 service.example.com,192.168.2.87 (RSA)
256  SHA256:6QZWKiXoFC8qRg3ZhClY4RcUPX8F2ROOREmysPT5JW9 example.com (ECDSA)
```

The actual known_hosts file will look something like this:

```
service.example.com,192.168.2.87 ssh-rsa AAAAB3NzaC1yc2EAAAABIwAAAQEA...8sw==
example.com ecdsa-sha2-nistp256 AAAAE2VjZHNhLXNo..C0N9T3Y4poTAXTuMyXZEPRywi28=
```

Each line in the `known_hosts` file contains the following fields: markers (optional), hostnames, keytype, base64-encoded
key, comment.  The fields are separated by spaces.

When  `HashKnownHosts` is set, the hostnames may be stored in a hashed form.  Hashed hostnames start with a `|` character.

Comment: whether i need to delete the fingerprint or i can leave like that. How to remove the user from that server?